# Can Derby database column entries contain white space?

Tags: javascript, jsp, derby

I am creating a simple user signup and login using Tomcat and embedded Derby database, but I have found that when i try to create a user account where the username contains a white space, I get an internal server error (500) thrown from the Javascript function which handles an Ajax post request to my sign up JSP form handler. In all other cases, it seems to be fine. Do I have to escape white spaces or something?

Comment: What is the actual code? What is the actual exception? What does your derby.log say? Try running with -Dderby.language.logStatementText=true, to see the actual statements that are executed.

Comment: turned out to be a silly error - I had set the length of that column to only 10 characters, so now I increase it whenever I encounter a long username!